# How to solve $\cos({r^{-4}}\cos 4\theta - {4\theta}) = 0$ for $\theta$ and $r$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-verification

**Problem Statement**

> How does one solve the trigonometric equation
>   $$\cos({r^{-4}}\cos 4\theta - {4\theta}) = 0$$ for $\theta$ and $r$?

**My Try**

Taking the inverse cosines of both sides, I get
$${r^{-4}}\cos 4\theta - {4\theta} = \cos^{-1}(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi.$$

Rearranging the last equation gives
$$\frac{\cos 4\theta}{4 \theta} - r^4 = \frac{{r^4}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\right)}{4 \theta}.$$

This is where I get stuck.

**QUERY**

> Of course, I know that I can rewrite the last equation as
>   $$\cos 4\theta = {r^4}\left(4\theta + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi\right).$$
>
> > Unfortunately, I do not know what to do or what approach to take past this point.  Should I use iteration to approximate the solution(s), if any?  Or is it (logically) possible to prove that there do not exist any solutions to this equation?

Thanks!

**Added September 15 2017**

Actually, I have
$$r = (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2} := f(x, y)$$
and
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) := g(x,y).$$
Does that help?

Comment: You **can't**, in general, solve a single equation for *two* unknowns.  Do you want to solve for r in terms of $\theta$ or vice versa?

Comment: solving for $r$ we get four Solutions containing $\theta$

Comment: Actually, I have $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$.  Does that help?

Comment: Note that solutions exist, since $\theta=0$,$r=(\pi/2)^{-1/4}$ is one of them. If you fix $\theta$, you can always find an $r$ that works for that $\theta$. That's just because the equation then becomes $\cos(ar^{-4}+b)=0$ for constants $a,b$.

Comment: @MPW, thanks!  Does your observation imply that the equation holds for all $\theta$ and $r$?

Comment: @MPW, hold on.  What about the $\theta$ for which $\cos 4\theta < 0$?  Surely no $r$ exists for such $\theta$?

Comment: Technically it does, but it will be complex. But I know what you mean, you are right. You will need to restrict $\theta$ appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, from the equation
$$\cos 4\theta = {r^4}\left(4\theta + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi\right),$$
and the equation
$$r = (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$$
I get that $r \geq 0$, so that
$$\cos 4\theta \geq 0.$$
This last inequality implies that
$$-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq 4\theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$
which implies that
$$-\frac{\pi}{8} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{8}.$$
(Note that, when $r = 0$, then $\theta = -\pi/8, \pi/8$.)
We now bound $r$ from above, given that
$$r^4 = \frac{\cos 4\theta}{4\theta + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi}.$$
An upper bound for $\cos 4\theta$ is given by $1$.  However, there is no lower bound for $4\theta + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$, since $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Thus, there is no [global](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize+(cos+x)%2F(x+%2B+a)) [maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize+(cos+x)%2F(x+-+b)) for
$$\frac{\cos 4\theta}{4\theta + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi}.$$
Hence, $r^4$ is not bounded from above.

Consequently, we conclude that the equation
$$\cos 4\theta = {r^4}\left(4\theta + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi\right)$$
is solvable when
$$\frac{-\pi}{8} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{8}.$$

Comment: There's no reason to assume $r>0$. In fact, if $(r,\theta)$ is a solution, then so is $(-r,\theta)$. Indeed, so are $(\pm ir,\theta)$.